# Has Darth Vader ever worn a different suit than his traditional black one?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

After Obi-Wan Kenobi defeated Darth Vader and left him for dead by the lava river on a volcanic world, Sidious rescued him and put him into the familiar full-body black suit.

[image: screen shot showing Darth Vader getting his suit fitted]

**Has Darth Vader ever worn a different suit?** (Not just another suit that looked like his typical one, but one that looked different.)

Please provide answers based on canon sources.

Comment: Depends if [Princess Vader](https://www.flickr.com/photos/8458869@N05/2719875578) is canon.

Comment: https://gunaxin.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/holiday-vader.jpg

Comment: I assume not, since the suit has become part of him and removing it would kill him. In *Return of the Jedi*, he asks Luke to remove the helmet even though it would kill him, seeing as he was dying anyway, However, I haven't read all Star Wars books and comics, so I can't say for sure if some writer ignored that.

Comment: @Klaus except we see Vader not wearing his helmet briefly in Empire, and floating without his suit in a bacta tank in Rogue One. So it can be removed in a suitable environment  - which the hangar of a disintegrating  death star probably  isn't.

Comment: @RichS what about interviews with an SFX supervisor who worked on the prequels and  remastered trilogy?

Comment: @KlausÆ.Mogensen Presumably it would only have killed him in those particular circumstances where the helmet was his only means of artificial respiration, because in *Empire Strikes Back* there is a brief glimpse of his helmet being replaced, so clearly it *can* be removed in the right circumstances. Something else must have kept him alive while the suit was being fitted, so in theory any part of the suit or helmet could also be replaced under the right conditions.

Comment: Damn. Now I'm picturing him in a hawaiian shirt and lederhosen.

Comment: He wore a red-and-white "Santa" cloak once at a Deathstar Construction Guild Christmas party.  But all of the kids tried to fiddle with the buttons on his chest control panel and one stuck some bubble gum in his helmet vents and then there was that force choke incident under the mistletoe ... anyway, it was just that one time - he swore he'd never again put up with that kind of sh**.

Comment: It's almost certainly non-canon, but in the 2014 Lego Star Wars Advent Calendar, he got a fearsome new look: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3fk4.jpg [(source)](https://imperialholocron.com/2014-lego-advent-calendar-day-24/)

Comment: ...and what does he do when it needs to go in the wash? ;-)

Comment: That pic of Vader looks like he is in a weight room.  Must be "thigh day"

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### Yes, from a certain point of view

I think before we get into the details of my answer it's worth noting why Vader might *not* have any different suits. In the Marvel comic series, *Star Wars: Darth Vader*, it is explained by Sidious that the armour ***is*** Vader and that he can modify it as he sees fit. If it is him it makes sense why he wouldn't want to wear another suit.

> **Darth Sidious:** *Ah*. I sense your anger. I should have known. This armor is **you** -- it is only appropriate that you should make it your own, especially with your skills as an engineer.
>
> **Darth Sidious:** Adjust the suit as you see fit, my apprentice. When you are ready, come to me. There is work to be done.

[image: Star Wars: Darth Vader page with Sidious explaining Vader is the suit, quoted above]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

---

I'm going to come right out with it, this answer *might* fall foul of the following statement: *"(Not just another suit that looked like his typical one, but one that looked different.)"*. However, it is worth mentioning because it *does* show he had different suits even if they were all very similar.

In the canon novel *Thrawn: Alliances*, it shows that Vader has more than one set. It's not entirely clear if this is the same suit or something different though.

> Vader would need his armor cleaned in more time-consuming detail. Fortunately, he had another full set in his quarters that he could wear while the *Chimera's* techs restored this one.
>
> <sub>*Thrawn: Alliances*</sub>

As we see throughout all of the films with Darth Vader in, his suit is always slightly different.

[image: Darth Vader's suit collage in each work]

This can be reasoned with out of universe logic with making a new suit each time so there are bound to be differences. However, John Knoll, the visual effects supervisor for the prequels and *Rogue One* (also executive producer and worked on the story in *Rogue One*), has stated he has different suits for different occasions.

> "That's a bit of a hybrid," Knoll said of Darth Vader's look in the film. "If you look in New Hope, especially like that white corridor scene at the beginning you can see all these smudges and all these fingerprints on there because it was cast from a clay sculpt. Then by the time we got to Empire Strikes Back they made a new one that was like really polished and smooth and shiny and perfect. The chest plate is different in every film.
>
> "We matched more the, what the chest plate looked like in Episode IV, but a little bit more of the high polish that's in Episode V."
>
> While not strictly official, Knoll even had some story reasoning in his own mind for the slightly different armor and outfit in each movie.
>
> "I figure he's got more than one version of those outfits. The reason the armor looks a little grungier and dented up in A New Hope is you're not going to wear your nice armor into battle. You're gonna wear your beater armor into battle. Then, if you're going to go talk to the Emperor or something you put on the nice shiny one, show some respect," Knoll said with a smile.
>
> <sub>[comicbook, EXCLUSIVE: Star Wars VFX Legend John Knoll Explains Darth Vader Costume Changes in Rogue One](https://comicbook.com/2016/12/06/exclusive-star-wars-vfx-legend-john-knoll-explains-darth-vader-c/)</sub>

Of course as the article states this isn't official but it does make a lot of sense. Also his suit is destroyed several times so it makes sense he would get new ones, upgrade parts and what not over the years.

And from another point of view he also wears different clothes when he first becomes Darth Vader *before* his injuries.

[image: Darth Vader marches on the Jedi Temple]

Lastly, in the Legends comic series *Star Wars Infinities: Return of the Jedi*, Vader once again becomes good and is Anakin, so this may not count. However, he does keep the same look but the armour is now white.

[image: Anakin in a white version of Vader's armour]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Comment: Boy, I bet *that* wardrobe change drew some comments... Planetary functionary: "Welcome to Numbular! I see you're now wearing white. Verrrrry attractive, Lord Vader!" Anakin Skywalker: "NO LONGER 'LORD VADER'! I *USED* TO BE ONE OF THE MOST EVIL HUMANS IN THE GALAXY, BUT NOW I AM SIMPLY ANAKIN SKYWALKER AGAIN!" PF: "Ummm...may I ask...why?" AS: "NO, YOU MAY NOT!" (Force-chokes PF) AS:"DID YOU HAVE ANY OTHER POINTLESS QUESTIONS?" PF: "gurgle! (\*thump!*)" AS: "I thought not..." Yoda: "Why do this, you did?" AS: "Whoopsie. Old habits. You know how it is. Heh..."

Comment: Note: the Infinities comic was never canon, unlike most Legends material, which is probably worth noting in the answer.

Comment: if this is the answer then wouldn't that make the question a duplicate of ths question? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/213547/did-darth-vader-wear-the-same-suit-for-20-years

Comment: That definitely wouldn't be canon, lol. Anakin was a force ghost at the end of VI.

Answer (score 0):

Anakin became Darth Vader before he had the armor, so technically he wore a suit of robes BEFORE he required the armor. So, to be fair, he did wear other things besides the armor.

Comment: I believe the question is about his armour suit, but the OP can clarify that if necessary.

Comment: I am asking about his armored suit. My question mentioned was about **after** Palpatine rescued him from the lava.

Comment: even if you consider his "robes" a different suit, this was already mentioned in the highest voted answer, so doesn't really add anything